# Finding max/min values and displaing them in a subform in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Good morning,

I'm building a form in Microsoft Access to track components/parts that go into building new products, and I have a question pertaining to the use of Min/Max values.

First, some context.  Slightly simplified*, the tables involved are:

1. *Components*: These are the pieces needed to build the widgets being sold

   *Suppliers*: These are the places where we can get components from. Some components are available at multiple locations at different price points.

   *Products*: The various widgets that can be built.

   *CompSuppliers*: Effectively a many-to-many relationship between Components and Suppliers.  Includes some additional information, such as unit price for each item from each supplier.

   *ProdComponets*: Effectively a many-to-many relationship between Products and Components.  Includes a few additional details, such as how many items are required to make the widget in question.

All tables have an autonumber ID field and all relationships are defined in the database.

I would like to make a form that brings this information together so that when viewing a given widget there is a sub-form that lists all the components that go into said widget, plus the best price & supplier for each part. On the main form I can then do a sum of these values to get a 'Best component price' (and similarly, a worst-case price if we have to go with more expensive suppliers) so that we can set an appropriate list price for the widget.

In the end, the form/subform should allow you to create a new widget, add all the components through the subform and give you a total parts cost (best case & worst case).

**Example:**

Building a Widgitizer requires 2 x Foo and 1 x Bar.

- Foo is available from Supercorp Prime for $1 ea

  Foo is also available from Emergicorp Alpha for $2 ea

  Foo is also available from Emergicorp Beta for $3 ea

  Bar is only available from Supercorp Prime for $5 ea

- In the components subform, Foo should appear with min cost $1 at Supercorp Prime, but worst-case is that we'd have to pay $3

  In the components subform, Bar should have min & max cost as $5, also from Supercorp Prime

  Best case it would cost (2x$1 + $5) = $7 in parts to build 1 Widgitizer

  However, if we can't get the parts from our preferred supplier for whatever reason it might cost as much as (2x$3 + $5) = $11 in parts to build a Widgitizer

I thought this would be relatively straightforward, but I can't seem to make this work and haven't been able to find any topics that were similar enough to show where I'm going wrong in my coding attempts.

Thank-you for any help/insight! Let me know if any additional details are needed.

~D

*The actual implementation is designed with a few extra complications, but if I can get the simple case described above working I should be good to expand it to work with what I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good well-designed start, but there's quite a lot to do.  Assuming you are decent with SQL (especially Group By queries), you can build a read-only form (the editable version is phase 2).  Here's the breakdown as I see it:

1. Make a query that will serve as the basis for your main form.  When done, you'll have 1 row of data per widget.
2. Make a query that will serve as the basis for your sub form.  This will include the mins and maxes per component.
3. Make a 3rd query that lists ALL the details down to the individual suppliers for each component. no mins or maxes here.
4. Build your sub form first.  It doesn't need alot of frills since it's going to be embedded.
5. Build your main form and embed the subform. Link the two by widget ID.
6. Build a 3rd form listing the individual suppliers for each component.
7. In the subform, add a button to the Detail section.  When pressed, this will pop up the 3rd form listing the individual suppliers and their prices.

Comment: I hadn't thought to use the third form - this just might work!  Thanks for the suggestion!